# Modifying internally identified username in Windows 8.1

Tags: windows, environment-variables, username

It's easy to change the display username in Windows 8.1, but I can't seem to figure out how to modify the internally identifying username (which can be seen on the Security window, which would say e.g. Robert (RobertsLaptop\Bob) if the user signed up as Bob but later changed his username). Registry modifications related to it are just reset on the next session and don't actually change the display; the same goes for changing the `USERNAME` environment variable. Is there some way to do this?

Comment: Are you using a Microsoft account?

Comment: @harrymc I am not, I'm on a standard user account.

Comment: Which registry modifications have you done that are reset on reboot?

Comment: `HKEY_USERS\snorepion\Volatile Environment\USERNAME` is the one that seems to be affected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix the issue using `lusrmgr.msc`; selecting the profile -> More Actions -> Rename seems to have done the trick, although you have to log out first or errors will occur. `netplwiz` can be used to fix the issue on versions lower than Professional, where `lusrmgr.msc` is not available.